# Where can I get the Visual Studio PDB files for ActivePython builds?

Tags: python, visual-studio, pdb-files, activepython

I currently have `ActivePython-2.7.2.5-win32-x86.msi` installed on my computer and python.exe is hanging.  I won't go into all of the details of this hang, but in order to continue debugging I have decided that it is necessary to debug the C code that makes up the Python interpreter.  I have successfully attached Visual Studio to the python.exe process.  The problem is that Visual Studio is looking for the debugging symbols for python.exe and I don't have them and don't know where to find them.

My question is: **Where can I get the pdb debugging symbols file for ActivePython builds, ideally ActivePython-2.7.2.5?**

I have searched everywhere I can think and have not had any success finding these files.  I have not been able to reproduce this issue with a self-compiled version of Python, which is why I am now trying to debug the actual distribution of Python that we use in our environment.